# LastDate-time when cell has been modified

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel spreadsheet
I am looking to know date-time when my excel cells have been modified last time.
Can I do it in Excel or Access?

If yes, what function I can use?

Thanx!

Comment: You need to accept some answers. :)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what do you mean

Comment: Sorry, I just found out how to accept answers! Thanx for the hint - I accepted the best answers, will be waiting for reply on my last...

Comment: This question is too vague at the moment; are you looking to track each individual cell or just the last time any cell was updated? Are you hoping to run against an open document, or perhaps a closed existing file?

Comment: To Matt Donnan:  <This question is too vague> It's been a long day. I am looking to know the last time any cell was updated. Hoping to run in an open document.  I need a function or vba script (and perhaps ) instruction how to run it) to see the last time my cell was updated

Comment: Are you hoping that there is a change log of some sort or do you have an updated date? I am fairly certain the the last update of the file is all you can get unless you set a last updated field / column. See also http://steveno.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/vba-excel-change-log/

Comment: I need to see the date-time of last updated field

Comment: Have you got a last updated field? Post sample data.

Comment: @Hell_77 Its only going to be a longer day if we can't understand the requirements ^_^, I'm still not 100% and share Remou's queries, however if it is as simple as knowing the last time an open spreadsheet was changed then you could google **Workbook_SheetChange** as this fires whenever a cell is updated, you may need something more complex than that but please elaborate more if possible.

Comment: @Remu:  I have Address field with data already entered. I need to know what date-time each address has been entered. I am not interested to know in what date-time the whole spreadsheet has been modified.  I am interested in "Address" - each record date-time last time entered.

Comment: Thanx everyone for explanations.  I confirmed that what I wanted to know - impossible to perform in excel or access...

Comment: @Hell_77, it's not IMPOSSIBLE, it's just not possible using functions ... But it is POSSIBLE ;)

Comment: @t.thielemans: got it. it's possible using other tools or programming but not functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Excel, you can **Track Changes**

[image: Review Menu, Track changes]

This opens up the workbook for sharing, and you can even tell Excel to track specific cells, and if you want your changes tracked or not.

[image: Changes dialog box]

This is an example of what you see when values are changed:

[image: example change]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Track Changes feature to find out the last modifier date of a cell and find who the user was.

How to Track Changes in Excel 2007

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/track-changes-in-excel/